# VirtualHost setup always doesn't work

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost, hosts

I'm trying to set up a virtualHost for mampstack (NOT MAMP). This is what I've done so far:

In my httpd.conf file I've checked

```
Listen 8080
```

This is correct (I'm listening to the port 8080, NOT 80).
Then I've uncommented: `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in my `httpd.conf` file

In my hosts file I have added the following: `127.0.0.1  mext-pst.local`.

In `httpd-vhosts.conf` I've added:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080> 
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/mampstack-5.4.20-0/apache2/htdocs"
    ServerName                127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias               localhost
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV    development
    SetEnv APPLICATION_DOMAIN localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080> 
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/mampstack-5.4.20-0/apache2/htdocs/mext-pst-dashboard/web"
    ServerName mext-pst.local
    ServerAlias mext-pst.local
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV    development
    SetEnv APPLICATION_DOMAIN mext-pst.local
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
    RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I go to `http://mext-pst.local/` I just get an error of my browser that he can't connect with the page ... .
When I go to `http://mext-pst.local:8080/` I get the following error:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /index.php.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: mext-pst.local:8080
```

When I go to `http://mext-pst.local:8080/index.php` it works ...

Comment: You must change port for Apache or use mod_proxy and `ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change 8080 to 80 its the default. But if you want your site to run on 8080, then you have to use it. Another solution might be to rewrite the url, that is when your server gets the url, it rewrites it with port number (8080).

First of all change Listen 8080 to Listen 80, as you want your application to be accessible only with http.
In your http-vhost.conf file put following lines (of course after removing previous changes). In the following configuration yourDefaultHttpFolder means the default http folder. You might have changed it. So correct it depending on your system.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
   DocumentRoot "/Applications/mampstack-5.4.20-0/apache2/htdocs/yourDefaultHttpFolder"
   ServerName                127.0.0.1
   ServerAlias               localhost
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV    development
   SetEnv APPLICATION_DOMAIN localhost

   <Directory /Applications/mampstack-5.4.20-0/apache2/htdocs/yourDefaultHttpFolder>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
      RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080> 
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/mampstack-5.4.20-0/apache2/htdocs/mext-pst-dashboard/web"
    ServerName mext-pst.local
    ServerAlias mext-pst.local
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV    development
    SetEnv APPLICATION_DOMAIN mext-pst.local       
 </VirtualHost>
```

This configuration is working on my server, when ever I try to access using 80 it rewrites the URL to my 8080 port and I see the content of that folder, not the the default index page.

Comment: I've changed 8080 to 80 (see topic post), but then I just get my localhost index.php

Comment: Ok it is the expected result when your configuration is considered. 
Please read about apache mod_rewrite module. It is a module to change requested urls on the fly.

Comment: I read about the mod_rewrite module but I can't figure out how to do this, could you post some code (example) to help me with this?

Comment: I have added the mod_rewrite to the post above.

Comment: I've updated my begin post, still having some difficulties. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok I have tried all on my server, it is working as expected. You did not put rewrite rules into <Directory> tags as I have explained before. I am correcting all of the above configuration.

Comment: Strange, still the same results... Only found at :8080

Answer (score 2):

You've got to change the port to *:80 and also if you're going to use a different name then the servername make sure to take up NameVirtualHost *:80 in your httpd.conf.

Comment: What do you mean with ' take up NameVirtualHost *:80 in your httpd.conf'?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not listening on port `80`, getting an error when you go to the URL without a port seems to be the correct result, right?

And when you go to port `8080` you are getting a `Proxy Error`. Are you sure there is no other software running on port `8080` or your browser doesn't have a proxy entered? `Apache` would not be giving a `Proxy Error`. I suspect this error is coming from somewhere else.

About your configuration, I am not exactly sure what it is that you are trying to achieve but, if you are trying to get some documents served when you go to `localhost:8080` and another set of documents served when you go to `mext-pst.local:8080` than you are almost there, `NameVirtualHost *:8080` is correct and needs to be there, remove redirect lines as you don't need them (unless my assumption is wrong).